# Transaction fails when attempting to initialize an auction program using Anchor

Tags: anchor, pda, error, sendtransactionerror, auction-house

I've deployed a program to devnet that lets me create English auctions, and I'm trying to create an auction from my next.js frontend. [This](https://github.com/udbhav1/solana-auctionhouse) is the program I'm using.

The process I'm following is roughly as follows:

1. connect wallet using wallet adapter (I'm testing with Phantom on devnet mode in Chrome)
2. mint an NFT using the Metaplex
3. approve the NFT to be transferred to the auction ATA
4. attempt to call createOpenAuction on the deployed program, which starts the auction and transfers the NFT to the custody of the auction program

The first few steps work, but on the 4th step I get `Failed to initialize auction: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0xbbf`. I researched 0xbbf and I believe the error in Anchor means `"AccountNotProgramOwned: The given account is not owned by the executing program"`.

I'm pretty new to Solana development, so I'm not sure how to interpret this. Is there something wrong with the way I'm sending the createOpenAuction transaction? I'd really appreciate any help!

This is the function in my frontend code where I try to start the auction:

```
  const handleInitAuction = async () => {
    if (!wallet.publicKey || !mintedNft) return;
  
    try {  
      const provider = new AnchorProvider(
        connection,
        wallet as any,
        AnchorProvider.defaultOptions()
      );
  
      const programIDL = idl as anchor.Idl;
      const program = new Program(programIDL, programID, provider);

      const auctionTitle = "Auction for " + mintedNft.name;
      const floor = new anchor.BN(reservePrice * web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
      const increment = new anchor.BN(0.05 * web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
      const biddercap = new anchor.BN(10);
      const amount = new anchor.BN(1);

      const mintPubKey = mintedNft.mint.address;

      const [auctionAddress, bump, auctionAta] = await deriveOpenAuction(programID, wallet.publicKey, mintPubKey, auctionTitle);

      console.log('auction address is ', auctionAddress.toBase58());

      console.log('auction ata is ', auctionAta.toBase58());  

      const ownerAta = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        mintPubKey,
        wallet.publicKey,
      );      

      // Create a transaction to approve the mintedNft for transfer to the auction program
      const approveTransaction = new Transaction().add(
        createApproveInstruction(
          ownerAta,
          auctionAta,
          wallet.publicKey,
          1,
          [],
          splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        )
      );

      console.log('using connection');
      console.log(connection);

      console.log('trying to approve nft for transfer to auction program');

      // Sign the transaction using the wallet adapter
      const approveSignature = await wallet.sendTransaction(approveTransaction, connection);

      console.log('NFT approved for transfer to auction program');

      const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

      await connection.confirmTransaction({
        blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
        signature: approveSignature
      });

      console.log('NFT approved for transfer to auction program');


      console.log('owner address is ', wallet.publicKey.toBase58());
      console.log('owner ata is ', ownerAta.toBase58());

      console.log('spl token program id is ', splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBase58());

      console.log('program methods');
      console.log(program.methods);

      const transaction = await program.methods.createOpenAuction(
        bump,
        auctionTitle,
        floor,
        increment,
        new anchor.BN(startTime),
        new anchor.BN(endTime),
        biddercap,
        amount,
      ).accounts({
        auction: auctionAddress,
        auctionAta: auctionAta,
        owner: wallet.publicKey,
        ownerAta: ownerAta,
        mint: mintPubKey,
        tokenProgram: splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        ataProgram: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        rentSysvar: web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
      }).transaction();

      if(wallet && wallet.signTransaction) {

        let blockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized')).blockhash;

        transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
        transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;

        const signed = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
        const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signed.serialize());
      }

      // const transactionSignature = await wallet.sendTransaction(transaction, connection);
        
      console.log("Auction initialized successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to initialize auction:", error);
    }
  };
```

I should also note that I'm following a very similar process in creating the auction to [the tests in the repo](https://github.com/udbhav1/solana-auctionhouse/blob/master/tests/auctionhouse.ts#L106). The tests work without issue on my machine's local cluster.

The rest of the frontend is [here](https://gist.github.com/mileshiroo/48604cb2b7bc546e8a63ada993fe9f41#file-page-tsx).